# DataTables warning: table id=patients - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have Issue with this Datatable Jquery i get  this Error:DataTables warning: table id=patients - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

I do this Function on controller:

```
  [HttpGet]
            public JsonResult LoadPatients()
            {
                // Browser list
                var totalPatientsList = _unitOfWork.Patients.GetPatients();
    
                var filteredResult = from b in totalPatientsList
                                     select new[] {b.Jeton, b.Nom, b.TelePhone, b.Adresse, b.Villes.Nom,b.Id.ToString()};
    
                return Json(new
                {
                    data =filteredResult
                },
                  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
and i call on index view :

$(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $("#patients").DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url:"/patients/LoadPatients",
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "jeton"
                        
                    },
                    {
                        data: "nom"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "telephone",
                        render: function (data) {
                            return data.toString().replace(
                              /(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/g, '$1-$2-$3');
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "adresse"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "villes.nom"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "id",
                        render: function (data, type, patient) {
                            return "<a href='/patients/details/ " + patient.id + "' class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>" + "<i class='fa fa-folder'></i>View</a>" +
                                //"<button class= 'btn-link js-detail' data-detail-id=" + data + "><i class='fa fa-pencil-square'></i></button>" +
                                "<button class= 'btn btn-danger btn-xs js-delete' data-patient-id=" + data + "><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>Delete</button>";
                        }
                    }

                ]
            });
```

I inspect result on chrome i get that:

```
{
    "data": [
        ["0002020", "patienta", "0670707070", "Zone franche", "Tan", "1"],
        ["0002029", "tst", "0524242424", "Ma", "M", "10"]
    ]
}
```

How can i resolve this Issue thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to include the data returned from your `/patients` URL. That data needs to be valid JSON, of course. (Also, the link in your question shows you how to diagnose this issue yourself.)

Comment: @andrewjames i get this respone but the data not display on datatable

Comment: Yes - that is understood.  But there will be data sent from the URL. You should be able to open that URL in any browser (just put the full URL into the address bar), or follow the diagnosis steps mentioned in your link ([this one](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1)).

Comment: @andrewjames when i get the url i have no data i have just this screenshot of the url :http://localhost:56778/Patients/Index  https://ibb.co/R3kNVhF

Comment: The URL `localhost:56678/patients` is the URL your DataTables page is trying to access in its ajax call, to fetch the raw JSON data it is trying to display. But it looks as if your JSON data is somewhere else - not at that URL - because that URL just takes you to the DataTables web page itself (circular). This is HTML, not JSON - hence the error you are getting.

Comment: @andrewjames how can i resolved this issue because i  have datatable empty

Comment: ajax: {
                    url:"~/api/patients",
                    dataSrc: ""
                }, and structure of the projet in below image https://ibb.co/TYhfCwt

Comment: Change that ajax URL to one which returns the JSON data you need. If there is no such URL, then you have to create it as part of your application. For example, [here](http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo) is a URL which returns pure JSON data. You need the equivalent of that for your "patients" data. Or, use the features of ASP.NET to return the data to your web page in whatever other way it provides.

Comment: @andrewjames i have this error when i changer the url Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Controllers/api/patients?_=1592678376801:1 how can i resolved that

Comment: The same answer as in my previous comment: It doesn't exist, so you have to create it as part of your application. Or, use the features of ASP.NET to return the data to your web page in whatever other way it provides. This has become a very broad question - I recommend you do some research, try some approaches, and, if needed, ask a new specific question.

Comment: @andrewjames i have return json but not display on datatable if you know this can y tell me please

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the JSON to the question.

Comment: @andrewjames I update the Question please can y see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON does not have any labels - each row is just a data array, for example:

```
["0002020", "patienta", "0670707070", "Zone franche", "Tan", "1"]
```

This means you **cannot** use data labels like this:

```
data: "jeton"
```

because the label `jeton` does not exist in your JSON data.

So, instead, you can change all of these `data:...` values to `title"...` - for example:

```
title: "jeton"
```

This means that the first value in the array (which is "0002020") will appear in the first column of your table - and the column heading will be "jeton".

And then the second column in your table will contain "patienta" and will use the column heading of "nom" - and so on.

Here is my example using your data:

[image]

I think that is all you need to do to fix the issue.

**Extra Notes:**

Don't forget to update the ajax URL - it loos like you may have already done that.

You may also need to remove the following `dataSrc: ""` line from the ajax section, so it is this:

```
ajax: {
  url:"/patients/LoadPatients"
},
```

- but I am not sure. Try it both ways.

Comment: Thank you (or should I say "hand-clap") @davidkonrad - much appreciated.

Comment: @andrewjames not worked for me i use title nom instead of data but not worked

Comment: {
                        Jeton: "jeton"
                        
                    },
                    {
                        Nom: "nom"
                    },
                    {
                        Telephone: "telephone",
                        render: function (telephone) {
                            return data.toString().replace(
                              /(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/g, '$1-$2-$3');
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        Adresse: "adresse"
                    },

Comment: Use "title" instead of "data". So, for example, `columns: [ { title: "jeton" }, { title: "nom" }, ... ]` and so on...

Comment: And note what davidkonrad says - you DO need to remove `dataSrc: ""`.

Comment: i do all that but not worked  ajax: {
                    url:"/patients/LoadPatients"
                   // dataSrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        title: "jeton"
                        
                    },
                    {
                        title: "nom"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "telephone",
                        render: fun

Comment: @Kamilia, dont know if it was ironically :) Hope this helps -> **https://jsfiddle.net/k42osety/1/**  andrewjames is right, the fiddle show how you should do it with the JSON sample. You do not have to use key/value JSON, string arrays are fine (see the fiddle)

Comment: Thank You Very much for @andrewjames and davidkonard

Comment: please @davidkonrad i have on equestion when i click on view  i can get the details id {
                        data: "id",
                        render: function (data, type, patient) {

Comment: @Kamilia the id would be in either `data` or `patient[5]` (if I understand your question correctly) So return `"<a href='/patients/details/" + data + "'` ... (remove the whitespace before /"!) would render as `/patients/details/1`... for the first row.

Comment: $.ajax({
                            url: "/patients/Delete",
                            //method: "DELETE",
                            success: function () {
                                table.row(button.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
                            }
                        });